# What is incorrect about this code? Its written in C

Tags: c

This code keeps giving the package weight must be greater then 0 output no matter what I input. How would I go about fixing this issue.

```
  #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
    #include <stdio.h> 

    int main(void)
    {
      
        double packageWeight = 0.0; 
        const double TWOPOUNDS = 1.25; 
        const double LESSSIX = 2.50; 
        const double LESSTEN = 3.90;
        const double OVERTEN = 4.40;
        double shippingCost = 0.00;

    
        printf("Enter the weight of the package: ");
        scanf("%.1lf", &packageWeight);

        if (packageWeight <= 2) {
        shippingCost = TWOPOUNDS; 
        }
        else if (packageWeight <= 6) {
            shippingCost = LESSSIX;
        }
        else if (packageWeight <= 10) {
        shippingCost = LESSTEN;
        }
        else if (packageWeight >= 10) {
        shippingCost = OVERTEN; 
        }
        if (packageWeight <= 0) {
                printf("The weight of the package must be greater than 0.00.\n");
        }
        else if (packageWeight > 0) {
            printf("The shipping charge is $%.2lf.\n", shippingCost);
        }
        return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Enable the compiler warnings, the `scanf` format is wrong.

Comment: What does `printf("Read packageWeight = %g\n", packageWeight);` print if placed immediately after the `scanf`?

Comment: @lightweightmcgee You mean, remove `double packageWeight = 0.0; `? As in, leave variable uninitialized? Please don't do that, and don't suggest that!

Comment: Always check return value of `scanf` (and any IO function, really, except printing to console).

Comment: Some simple debugging would help you find the error and remind you to *ALWAYS* check if input was successful or not. https://ideone.com/PFI0BS

Comment: use your debugger, you will see that packageweight is 0.0 after the scanf, you now know to go and investigate why your scanf didnt work. You would have found out that something went wrong if you looked at the return value of scanf

Comment: @zvol It's still a very good idea to initialize every variable, when learning. No reason to skip that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good eye, I had to reread the scanf manpage twice to realize `%.1` was invalid.

Comment: @zwol Hah, I didn't look at the format string at all, only at the warnings.

Comment: @hyde,.Re "*As in, leave variable uninitialized? Please don't do that,*" No, as in don't initialize it twice. `scanf` will be giving it a value, and there's no point in giving it a value before that (...if you check that `scanf` succeeded, but that's a given in my book).

Comment: @lightweight mcgee Re "*remove the "= 0.0" on packageWeight and it should run just fine?*", No, that won't help.

Comment: @ikegami Uninitialized variables have a tendency to bite the programmer in the ass, if you have a habit of having them. Trust me on this. Especially here, using it as `scanf` parameter will even block any warnings about using uninitialized variable if `scanf` fails.

Answer (score 0):

anyway , your scanf is wrong, corrected below. Plus you should be dealing with invalid input

```
while (true) {
    printf("Enter the weight of the package: ");
    int ret = scanf("%lf", &packageWeight);
    if (ret == 1)
        break;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

the extra logic detects if the user enters say, 'dunno' at the prompt

Comment: A good answer would say what is wrong with the `scanf` and why, not just “your scanf is wrong.” And code should be explained, more so than is in this answer. Stack Overflow should not be just a service for giving code to people; it should provide useful information.